# Change iOS System Keyboard Background Image and Buttons Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard

Rather than creating a custom keyboard...how can I change the ios keyboard background image and get reference of the keyboard button or just the keyboard view programatically?

I do not want to replicate the whole ios keyboard, just tweak the keyboard here and there.

**Solution Update:**

You cannot update only the background or the buttons of the iOS System Keyboard! This is dues to the reason that Apple has limited the access to the Keyboard API. The most you can do is change the keyboard background color i.e. dark or light.

If you need to change the background to an image like me, you need to  extend the ios keyboard i.e. make your own custom keyboard!

Please check below for accepted answer!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
 myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad; // many other options

 myTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark; //many other options
```

If you want totally customize keyboard then refer [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For dark background you can use

```
mytextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```

For more customisation follow this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html